# Error: IntegerField should be set to int, not float

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models, form-fields

I am relatively new to all of this but I have created an IntegerField(). After some time, I noticed that I need a FloatField() for that. However, when I change the IntegerField() to FloatField(), I get the Error: "IntegerField should be set to int, not float".

I try to sum up the number of trees (=no_trees) for every round with:

```
self.player.cumulative_donated_trees = sum([p.no_trees for p in self.player.in_all_rounds()])
```

When I leave the no_trees field as an IntegerField() and type in something like 0.9, I obviously get 0 in return. But I need to get 0.9. 
self.player.cumulative_donated_trees = float(self.player.cumulative_donated_trees) is giving me the same Error message btw.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we see your model? And you remembered to migrate?

Comment: I guess posting the whole model is quite hard because it is quite long. But what do you mean with migrate? Shouldn't it work if I just change the type?

Comment: Did you not run something like `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I didn't. Where do I have to run it?

Comment: In the folder with your manage.py file.

Comment: I've posted a screenshot of my manage.py files. If I type in what you texted, it is underlined in red

Comment: Please put the screenshots into your question, not into answers. Better still, copy and paste the text from those screenshots. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267479/how-to-upload-an-image for information on how to upload an image.

Answer (score 1):

I think they deleted my comment under your other screenshot, so here is the procedure.

You look like you are using Pycharm. In the very bottom left, there should be a button which says “Terminal.”

Click on it.

Now go to your file tree (the list of files typically on the left side of Pycharm), and locate the directory where manage.py is.

Now, check that the path of that directory matches the path in your terminal.

If it does, skip the next step.

If it doesn’t, you need to navigate your Terminal to that directory. The most probable thing you will need to enter into your terminal is

`cd YourProjectName`

Once you are in the correct directory, enter into your terminal:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

If that works fine without errors, do:

`python manage.py migrate`

That should resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi Matthew, first of all thank you very much for that detailed description, I managed to follow your steps one by one. However, if I insert ```python manage.py makemigrations``` it says "No changes detected", although I've definitely changed the Field types from IntegerField() to FloatField(). Do you know by any chance why this may happen?

Comment: Is there anything in the migration folder of your app?

Comment: With each app, or in the Django setup as a whole, there should be a migrations folder. What is in there?